# Regarding UART logging in terminal

Tags: logging, terminal, adb, uart

I am working in a Buds project which runs on RTOS. We can only get logs through UART port. Is there any way to see UART logs in terminal? I am using GitBash/ CMD in Windows.

I am looking for ways (possibly by commands) to show those UART logs in my terminals similar to when I see ADB logs using ADB commands.

Comment: Sorry but what are you referring to by "UART logs"? Android by default has no serial connection, only an USB connection which runs adb (which you already seem to know). If this question is not about android please don't tag it `adb` (adb is an Android specific interface).

Comment: @Robert I think you misunderstood the question. I said any commands to see UART logs "LIKE" there are adb commands. However, I have modified the text for better undestandings. Could you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand properly what you were trying to convey.

I assume you wish to view your UART log on PC/Development Host.

You can use tools such as [CoolTerm](https://freeware.the-meiers.org/) or [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) or minicom (on Linux).

With PuTTY and minicom you will get native console like feel.

You will need to configure your serial port setting for your Board, RTOS and Logger. Most board use the following setting (but you will need to confirm with your board & RTOS)

1. Baud Rate    : 115200
2. Data Bits    : 8
3. Stop Bits    : 1
4. Parity       : None
5. Flow-Control : None/Disabled

You will also need to select appropriate port. One can refer to your device manager on Windows and dmesg command output on Linux.

ADB works on either on USB or Ethernet or Wi-Fi. Its quite different from how UART logs are handled.

Comment: You are on the same pace. I have all these settings from the Board, Just trying to know how can I associate them with commands (possibly with PuTTY params)... Thanks in advance

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan What commands are you trying to associate them with?

Comment: Using PuTTY/ CMD - is there any api to read logs from serial UART? for example, "showlogs -BR 115200 -DB 8 -SB 1 -P none" or similar? @DarkSorrow

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan What you have to do is just open the Serial Terminal and open (connect) the port with proper settings.
The Serial Utility will keep on looking data from serial port and once data is available it will display the data on UI. You don't need additional commands.

Comment: Is there any tutorial/reference to open serial terminal with port? @DarkSorrow

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/coolterm-windows-mac-linux

https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2021/01/20/serial-terminal-basics-with-coolterm/

Answer (score 0):

I normally use SerialTool [www.serialtool.com](https://www.serialtool.com) which is a free tool for Windows, MacOS and Linux which is half way between a Terminal and a Serial Communication tool. I is graphically more agressive than CoolTerm or Putty and allows you to combine Hex and ASCII commands hence a good combination between a Serial sender and a Terminal.